# Quick simple car lighting circuit question

Tags: circuit-design, ground, lighting, toggle-switch

I have wired up the below circuit in my car and would just like to ask if there are any issues with this circuit.

The lighting in this circuit is tapped into three wires from the car's ceiling light. These three wires are as follows:

1. +12v feed
2. GND constant
3. GND only when car doors open

The front LEDs are functioning properly whether the switch is set to "GND constant" or "GND only when doors open."

But the right and left side LEDs are not functioning at all. I have them wired into "GND only when doors open" as I do not want them constantly on and only want them to come on when a car door is open.

[image: quick simplified circuit sketch]

[image: original circuit diagram I created and followed]

Thank you so much for looking and I appreciate any help.

Comment: What are these LEDS? Specs?

Comment: Hi, they're 12V LED strips, with a current of less than 0.5A according to the manufacturer.

Comment: So when you flip the switch to the left, do the front LEDS operate with open door?

Comment: If the LED strips are dedesigne to operate from 12 volts, they should be connected in parallel, not series as your drawings indicate.  If two strips are connected in series, they will each see 6 volts, and probably won't light.

Comment: Hi Eugene, yes when flipped to the left, the front LEDs light only operate with the doors open, when flipped to the right the front LEDs light up constantly. But the side LEDs do not light up at all.

Comment: Hi Peter is there an easy solution that involves not having to remove the seats and the carpets to dig up the wiring and change from series to parallel (maybe a resistor or something), i have access to the wires at the point where it splits into three but beyond that the wiring is now deeply tucked away under the carpet of the car and cable tied.

Comment: when the switch is flipped to the left, there is no any difference between the front and the other LEDs with regards to connection. Therefore the only issue might be the wiring.

Comment: Eugene, I think you're correct, as Peter said I think I should have wired in parallel instead of series because the voltage is being split between each strip on the left side and each strip on the right side, therefore all individual LED strips are receiving 6V instead of 12V. (these strips can run off of 12v-18v. So maybe the 6v jist isn't enough. I don't know if I can just use a 12v to 24v converter for each side. (access to the wiring is now very difficult because everything would have to be removed to get to the wires. Thanks

Comment: You should probably disassemble and fix it.  Take it as a lesson to test next time before you move on to finishing.  You've also drawn them as two different size fixtures, and if that's the case, they won't share voltage evenly in series.